# Set display:none if element contains no text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if **.pp-post-content-awards** and **pp-post-content-location** have no Text in them.

If not set display:none for both as well as the previous elements before them which would be .pp-post-content-subtitle for both.

There are several instances of these down the DOM but only want to remove the empty ones and the element before it which is the subtitle.

I know I got to use .each() but can't quite figure out how.

```
<div id="pp-post-right-{post_id}" class="pp-post-right">
    <span class="pp-post-content-subtitle">Location</span>
    <div class="pp-post-content-location">{%ptb_location%}</div>
    <span class="pp-post-content-subtitle">Accolades &amp; Awards</span>
    <div class="pp-post-content-awards">{%ptb_accolades_and_awards%}</div>
</div>


$('.pp-post-content-location').each(function() {
   let locationContent = $(''this').text();
   if (locationContent = '') {
      $('this').css('display','none');
   }
});


$('.pp-post-content-awards').each(function() {
   let awardsContent = $('this').text();
   if (awardsContent = '') {
      $('this').css('display','none');
   }
});
```

Comment: As a side note you should architect the HTML differently. You shouldn't have your titles and subtitles flopping around in such a manner - they should each be wrapped in their own div. That way you don't have to ask hacky question like "how do I hide an empty element and the one before it" - you would just need to hide one element, which contains both the title and subtitle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector

> Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).

```
$('.pp-post-content-location:empty, .pp-post-content-awards:empty').hide()
```

---

Problem with you implementation is usage of `this` which is refers to current element in iteration hence should not be in quotes and `=` is assignment operator you need to use `==`/`===` for comparison.

```
$('.pp-post-content-location').each(function() {
   let locationContent = $(this).text();
   if (locationContent == '') {
      $(this).css('display','none');
   }
});
```

Comment: how would i hide the previous element in front of it if it is empty then?

Comment: @gcollins `$('.pp-post-content-location:empty').prev().hide()`

Answer (score 0):

`let locationContent = $(''this').text();` **=>** `var locationContent = $(this).text();`

```js
$('.pp-post-content-location').each(function() {
   var locationContent = $(this).text();
   if (locationContent == '') {
      $(this).css('display','none');
   }
});


$('.pp-post-content-awards').each(function() {
   var awardsContent = $(this).text();
   if (awardsContent == '') {
      $(this).css('display','none');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pp-post-right-{post_id}" class="pp-post-right">
    <span class="pp-post-content-subtitle">Location</span>
    <div class="pp-post-content-location"></div>
    <span class="pp-post-content-subtitle">Accolades &amp; Awards</span>
    <div class="pp-post-content-awards">{%ptb_accolades_and_awards%}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="pp-post-right-{post_id}" class="pp-post-right">
    <span class="pp-post-content-subtitle">Location</span>
    <div class="pp-post-content-location">{%ptb_location%}</div>
    <span class="pp-post-content-subtitle">Accolades &amp; Awards</span>
    <div class="pp-post-content-awards">{%ptb_accolades_and_awards%}</div>
</div>


$('.pp-post-content-location').each(function() {
   let locationContent = $('this').text(); //corrected this
   if (locationContent == '') { //corrected this
      $('this').css('display','none');
   }
});


$('.pp-post-content-awards').each(function() {
   let awardsContent = $('this').text();
   if (awardsContent == '') {// corrected this
      $('this').css('display','none');
   }
});
```

= used for assignment.

== linient equality

=== strict equality

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.pp-post-content-awards').each(function(){
if (!$(this).text().trim().length) {
    $(this).css('display','none');
}});
```

Tried This one with your code and worked. Used Jquery function trim and get the length to make sure that it doesnt only contain whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".pp-post-right").each(function(){
str1 = $.trim($(".pp-post-content-awards").html()).length;
str2 = $.trim($(".pp-post-content-location").html()).length;
if(str1 == 0 && str2 == 0)
{
$(this).find(".pp-post-content-subtitle,.pp-post-content-location,.pp-post-content-awards").hide();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below snippet :

```js
$('.pp-post-content-location li').each(function() {
   let locationContent = $(this).text();
   console.log(locationContent)
   if (locationContent == '') {
      $(this).css('display','none');
   }
});


$('.pp-post-content-awards').each(function() {
   let awardsContent = $('this').text();
   if (awardsContent = '') {
      $('this').css('display','none');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pp-post-right-{post_id}" class="pp-post-right">
    <span class="pp-post-content-subtitle">Location</span>
    <div class="pp-post-content-location">                      <li>America</li>
    <li>America</li>
    <li>America</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>America</li>
    </div>
    <span class="pp-post-content-subtitle">Accolades &amp; Awards</span>
    <div class="pp-post-content-awards"><p>
    
    </p></div>
</div>
```